# Generating PGP signatures from a Scala program

Tags: java, scala, input, gnupg

I am writing a small Scala script to generate PGP signatures for all the files in the current directory. This is what I wrote:

```
object PGPSign {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
    signFilesInDirectory(new java.io.File("."))
  }

  def signFilesInDirectory(dir: java.io.File) {
    if(!dir.exists())
      throw new java.io.FileNotFoundException
    if(!dir.isDirectory())
      throw new RuntimeException("Expecting directory")
    println("Signing files in: " + dir.getAbsolutePath())
    for{ file <- dir.listFiles 
      if !file.isDirectory //ignoring directories
      val fileName = file.getName()
      if !fileName.startsWith(".") //ignoring hidden files
    } { 
      ("gpg -ab " + fileName).!!
    }
  }
}
```

In the console, the command `gpg -ab FILE_NAME` will request a password. When I execute my scala script I got this exception at the point of invoking the external command:

```
gpg: cannot open tty `/dev/tty': Device not configured
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 2
at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.slurp(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:131)
at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:101)
at PGPSign$$anonfun$signFilesInDirectory$3.apply(PGPSign.scala:25)
at PGPSign$$anonfun$signFilesInDirectory$3.apply(PGPSign.scala:20)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:743)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:34)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:38)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:742)
at PGPSign$.signFilesInDirectory(PGPSign.scala:20)
at PGPSign$.main(PGPSign.scala:11)
at PGPSign.main(PGPSign.scala)
```

I have the idea this is related to the fact that the external command (gpg in this case) requests some input.
If this is what is creating the problem(?), what is the easiest general way to make any external command (requesting any amount of inputs) to work when executed from Scala ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gpg expects to be able to read from/write to a tty, which is not available unless gpg is started from an interactive shell. You should use the `--no-tty` option to disable this behavior. Also, you probably want batch mode, enabled with `--batch`.

Comment: hi @Kim. If I add the --no-tty option I receive this exception instead: "gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input"
I see that exception both when I execute the Scala script or if I execute the command directly in the console.

Comment: so what input does it need? can you supply that on the command line?

Comment: it asks for the passphrase, but do not know how to include it in the command line (I skipped over the man documentation without luck until now)

Comment: Finally it stopped throwing the exception with this line:
("gpg -ab --yes --batch --passphrase " + passPhrase + " " + fileName).!!

Thanks for the help @Kim, at least it solved my immediate problem. Still I am wondering if it is possible to invoke any command from Scala and being able to provide input to it when it requires it

Comment: @Sergio: that depends on the kind of "input". Of course it is possible to write to the program's standard input, but gpg wasn't reading from stdin.